# Getting error when build production build with webpack and extract-text-plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I have an error when trying to build a production build of my React application:

```
/home/andrey/Projects/Datarisk/app-frontend/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:28
            if(c.isInitial()) return;
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isInitial' of undefined
```

This is my webpack production config:

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import ManifestPlugin from 'webpack-manifest-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import globals from './globals';

const { SRC_PATH, DIST_PATH } = globals;

export default {
  entry: {
    app: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      path.resolve(SRC_PATH, './client/index.js')
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: DIST_PATH,
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(SRC_PATH, './client'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(SRC_PATH, './client/components'),
      '@': path.resolve(SRC_PATH, './client'),
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].[chunkhash].css"),
    new ManifestPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
      'process.env.BROWSER': JSON.stringify(true),
    }),
  ],
}
```

I am using the following versions:

- Webpack: **v2.6.0**
- extract-text-webpack-plugin: **v2.1.0**
- Node: **v6.9.4**

I also use CSS Modules with SASS.

Thank you.

Comment: NodeJS version?

Comment: I am using Node v6.9.4

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting a similar error and am completely unsure where to start trying to debug